# What b12 surplus cause and how much is too much?

Tags: micronutrients, weight

If you need to gain weight(due to having a low BMI), I was wondering if consuming B12(pills) will lead to your body to creating a balance and help you gain weight.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! Questions asking personal medical questions are not allowed on the site, because your doctor can always answer them better. I will try to edit your question so that it no longer portrays this. See the Help center or ask here for more questions. Thank you!